# Comparing Dates in Swift 2.1 Ascending is the Same as Earlier?

Tags: swift, nsdate, uidatepicker

I'm very confused when using the date picker. If I try to compare dates like this, the results are the same for earlier dates as they are for the dates when they are the same:

```
@IBAction func datePickerChanged() {

        let date = NSDate()
        if datePicker.date.compare(date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
            print("Date picked: \(datePicker.date) is later than current date: \(date)")
        } else if datePicker.date.compare(date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
            print("Date picked: \(datePicker.date) is earlier than current date: \(date)")
        } else if datePicker.date.compare(date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame {
            print("Date picked: \(datePicker.date) is same as current date: \(date)")
        }

}
```

Results:

> Date picked: 2015-11-11 18:29:40 +0000 is earlier than current date:
>   2015-11-12 18:29:43 +0000
>
> Date picked: 2015-11-12 18:29:40 +0000 is earlier than current date:
>   2015-11-12 18:29:49 +0000
>
> Date picked: 2015-11-13 18:29:40 +0000 is later than current date:
>   2015-11-12 18:29:54 +0000

WTF? No, 2015-11-12 is not earlier than 2015-11-12...  it's the same.

Comment: The dates are not the same. NSDate describes an absolute point in time with (about) microseconds precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparisons are all correct. The day is the same but if you look at the hours, minutes and seconds, they are not the same and this is giving you accurate results.

If you want to compare only the days, you can construct a new date (for each date you want to compare) from its date components (see NSDateComponents documentation) - only adding in the components you want to check, which are the year, month, and day - and then do the comparison.

Edit: Leo Dabus pointed out that you can use NSCalendar to do date comparisons and it's much slicker than creating new dates and comparing that way.

NSDate isn't just a "date" comparison - "time" comparison is built in there as well.

Comment: This is the correct answer; `NSDate` is a misleading name in my opinion but you can think of it as `NSTimestamp`, which is what the more-or-less equivalent method in WebObjects was called except that, ironically, that also initially has an associated time zone and vended date components. So I think the slightly unhelpful name might be about a conscious break with the immediate past.

Comment: No need to construct a new date. NSCalendar has a method isDate(inSameDayAsDate:) to make those comparisons. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/isDate:inSameDayAsDate:

Comment: Trying to figure out from these comments what I need to do instead but I understand why it isn't working now.

Comment: Nathan, use Leo's suggestion to compare them - "NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDate(date1, inSameDayAsDate: date2)". I had forgotten about that method.

Comment: I am trying, but NSCalendar.isDateInToday method wants something besides an NSDate, I don't know what to give it or what it wants or how to tell it the date from the datepicker. It doesn't want datePicker.date. It's being self-referential.

Comment: I just edited my earlier comment to give a better example. You have to grab the current calendar first. There are other methods to as if it's earlier than today or if it's in the same week, etc. Check out NSCalendar. It's pretty awesome.

Comment: Thanks I figured part of it out but the problem is I just need to know if it's in the future, same day or in the past, not specifically tomorrow or yesterday.  What if it's two days in the future?

Comment: There's a method in NSCalendar for that. Check out compareDate in the NSCalendar documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare the days, and not the times, then use the `NSCalendar` method `compareDate:toDate:toUnitGranularity:`

```
if NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(datePicker.date, 
                                     toDate:date, 
                          toUnitGranularity:NSCalendarUnit.Day) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
{ ...
}
```

This compares according to the day boundaries in the local timezone.